# Write or burn a bootable cd/dvd from a virtual machine in Virtual Box?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, burning, bootable-media, disc

I have a virtual machine (Ubuntu 11) running on VirtualBox and have some of my projects in it, I want to burn it on a cd/dvd  so that when I insert the cd/dvd onto some other system I can boot and browse through my project files.Any idea how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to make a custom LiveCD, in which case you want to check out https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Comment: WHile this may technically answer the question, we prefer if you replicate the main points here, what if that link breaks in the future?